# copying of two arrays and console output

Tags: javascript

How come console shows "potato" instead of "JAN" when you console out `arr2`?

`arr1[0]='Potato'` is done after the line 4, so why `arr2` is not equal to initial `arr1`? (array at line 1)

[image]

Comment: because it's only a reference, you don't have 2 different variables. also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: In JS compound values (Object, Array) are assigned-by-reference, so arr2 is just a reference to the original array. Changing the original will also change the reference. See [Learning how references work in JavaScript](https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600)

Comment: Clearly understood .Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Both variables have an instance of the same array.

If you want to avoid that, make something like this instead `const arr2 = [...arr1]`. That will create new array with same elements as the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make new array from variable 1

Just try:

```
let arr2 = Array.from(arr1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const arr2 = [...arr1];` to immutable array clone

```js
var arr1 = ['JAN', 'FEB'];

const arr2 = [...arr1];

arr1[0] = 'Potato';

console.log(arr2)
```

`